# Get index within v-for using computed or method

Tags: methods, vue.js, computed-properties, v-for

I was wondering if it is possible in vue to get the index of an object array directly within the v-for in and pass this value to a computed property or a method, similar to this here, or even a computed property

```
<div v-for="(object, index) in objects(index)"></div> 

methods: {
   objects(index){
    const categoryId = Object.keys(this.data);
    return this.data[categoryId[index]].extras;
   } 
}
```

I need to have the index as it is more convenient for me to return the correct value based on defined key, is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: uses methods instead of computed.

Comment: no. computed properties cannot have parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform your data using a computed value and loop over that. I am not sure what your `this.data` looks like, but something like this should work (tweak it to suit your needs):

```
<div v-for="object in computed_objects"></div> 

computed: {
   computed_objects(){
    return Object.keys(this.data).map(categoryId => this.data[categoryId].extras)
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a method call on each element created by the `v-for` **directive**, so for example any time a user clicks on `<li>` element, it will gets the index of that clicked item:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    clickedIndex: null,
    weekDays: ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday']
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick(i) {
      this.clickedIndex = i;
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(day,i) in weekDays" v-on:click="handleClick(i)">{{day}}</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Index clicked {{ clickedIndex }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I do see that I have not explained my use case too well, I do not need to implement a way of clicking on different elements, I would only need to pass the index from each element into a computed property or method to return the correct value in the object array